# Why do interleaved scanf() + printf() statements result in both scanf() calls executing first, then both printf() calls?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Can you please explain one thing in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;char ch,ch1;
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    printf("d-%d \n",n);

    scanf("\n%c",&ch);
    printf("ch-%d \n",ch);

    scanf("\n%c",&ch1);
    printf("ch1-%d \n",ch1);

    printf("%d %d %d\n",n,ch,ch1);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it that after entering the value of n,it directly asks for the value of ch and then directly executes the statements to print their respective values ie the statements:

```
printf("d-%d \n",n);
printf("ch-%d \n",ch);
```

Comment: Ugh. Not sure where my comments are, perhaps there has been some data loss. Anyway, @OP: since this is a question that can directly be answered by reading [`man 3 scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html), it is not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, [dupe1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934304/cant-understand-whitespace-handling-in-scanf), [dupe2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920907/cant-understand-the-codes-behaviour). (This user is asking the same question twice a day. That's not normal.)

Comment: Re-opening since I *just* closed one of the other questions as a duplicate of this (and the other as a duplicate of that).

Comment: @Shog9 Shouldn't the original one be left open and the two later ones be closed as dupes?

Comment: This was the best of the three, IMHO. The first one in particular deserved that "minimal understanding" closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf("%d\n",&n);` skips any number of trailing white-spaces (including none) after actual the input. It can also be written as`scanf("%d ",&n);`.

`scanf("\n%c",&ch);` skips any number of leading white-spaces (including none) before the actual input. It can also be written as `scanf(" %c",&ch);`.

**NOTE:** A white-space in a format specifier is able to skip any number of white-spaces.

Now what does it mean by *skipping white-spaces* ?

It means `scanf` repeatedly reads white-space characters from input until it reaches a *non-white-space* character. Now **there is no white-space characters left in the buffer**.
When it encounters a *non-white-space* character, then this character is *put back* to be read again during the scanning of the next input item or during the next call of `scanf`.

Now coming to your question.

> Why do interleaved `scanf()` + `printf()` statements result in both `scanf()` calls executing first, then both `printf()` calls?

I am assuming the input for `n` is `15`. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key then the `\n` character goes with `15` in the input buffer. `scanf("%d\n",&n);` reads the `15` and then skips `\n`. Now this `scanf` waits for a *non-white-space* character to be entered (unlike what you supposed that `15` should be printed) . When you enter `a`, it puts it back for the next call of `scanf`. The next statement `scanf("\n%c",&ch);` reads this `a` from the buffer and do not let the user to input the value for `ch`. Since the value of `n` and `ch` both is now read by these `scanf`s, it appears to be that both of

```
printf("d-%d \n",n);
printf("ch-%d \n",ch);
```

executes after both of the `scanf`s call (which is not the case!).

Comment: I tried my best. Hope you will understand. If you have any question regarding this , then let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Any whitespace in a `scanf` format is like any other whitespace in a `scanf` format. It simply tells `scanf` to skip any whitespace in the input.

Most format codes doesn't need it though as they skip leading whitespace automatically, but one that does (unless you want to actually read a whitespace character) is the `"%c"` format code.

You might also want to read [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: according to me, the OP problem is in understanding the buffered nature of the input and the fact that the `\n` char is around although invisbile — but I may be wrong of course